# Summing over first 2D of 3D matrix

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

Suppose I have a 3D matrix `A` of size (1,2,3). Something like

```
A(:,:,1) = 
[1 2]

A(:,:,2) =
[3 4]

A(:,:,3) =
[5 6]
```

How would I go about finding the 3 values that make up the sum of the first two dimensions, for example.

```
sum(A(:,:,1)  = 3
```

The above works, but when I try it for an array with larger dimensions, say `A` is size (5,5,5), then I get a 2D array back as an answer but I want a single value summing up the value of that array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `reshape` inside your `sum` to put each 2D matrix into a single column:

```
sum(reshape(A,[],size(A,3)))
```

For example:

```
>> A = randi(3,2,3,3)
A(:,:,1) =
     1     3     1
     2     2     1
A(:,:,2) =
     1     2     2
     1     2     3
A(:,:,3) =
     2     2     1
     3     3     3
>> sum(reshape(A,[],size(A,3)))
ans =
    10    11    14
```

Our you could do `sum(sum(...))`.

**EDIT**: Generalized with `size(A,3)`.

Comment: @user1431626 I fixed the command so it is generalized, working when `size(A,3)` is any number, not just 3.

Answer (score 1):

The Matlab `sum()` function has a `sum(A,dim)` calling form that lets you operate along a given dimension. So you could do `sum(sum(A,1),2)`. This would produce a 1-by-1-by-3 array that's the result of summing along the first two dimension. You could generalize this to other dimensions and reshape the output as you see fit. Based on your description, it looks like the problem you're running in to is that `sum()` only operates along one dimension at a time, and by default the first dimension, instead of all but the last dimension in a multidimensional array.